# How to check UIbarbutton class in UItoolbar

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, subviews

I am using a toolbar with UIbarButton items, and i had given tags for that, In one scenario i need to get all the subviews of the Toolbar and disable one Button

```
                    for (id toolBarSubView in [self.topToolBar subviews]) {

                        NSLog(@"toolBarSubView details %@",toolBarSubView);

                        if ([toolBarSubView isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]] && [toolBarSubView tag] == 103) {
                            UIButton* backButton = (UIButton*)toolBarSubView;
                            backButton.enabled = YES;
                        }
                        else if([toolBarSubView isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]] && [toolBarSubView tag] == 102)
                        {

                            UIButton* navigationTitle = (UIButton*)toolBarSubView;
                            navigationTitle.enabled = NO;
                        }
                        else if([toolBarSubView isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]] && [toolBarSubView tag] == 104)
                        {
                            UIButton* infoButton = (UIButton*)toolBarSubView;
                            infoButton.enabled = NO;
                        }
```

I am using above code, i am trying to find the class name like this [toolBarSubView isKindOfClass:[UIBarButtonItem class]

But the condition is failing none of the condition is success, Which class i have to in the console it is some thing like this
**2013-09-13 12:15:35.943 Receipts[1544:60b] toolBarSubView details >**
2013-09-13 12:15:35.945 Receipts[1544:60b] toolBarSubView details >
**2013-09-13 12:15:35.947 Receipts[1544:60b] toolBarSubView details >**

Answer (score 0):

If you put UIButton in UIToolBar instead of UIBarButtonItem in UIToolBar, by default UIButton comes under UIBarButtonItem. Then you can check like this,

```
if([toolBarSubView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && [toolBarSubView tag] == 10)
{}
```

If you want to check particular UIBar button item in UIToolbar,do like this

```
NSArray *barButtons = [self.topToolBar items];
    for(UIBarButtonItem *myBarButton in barButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",myBarButton.tag);
        if(myBarButton.tag == 103)
        {}
    }
```

Comment: I did that for the Barbutton i am using button, But i have one condition where i have to definitely use UIbarbuttonitem default How can i handle it

Comment: then you must check like this NSArray *barButtons = [self.topToolBar items];
    for(UIBarButtonItem *myBarButton in barButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"%d",myBarButton.tag);
        if(myBarButton.tag == 103)
        {// do your work here}
    }